# Watson Explorer Text Analysis and SPSS modeller

Tags: nlp, spss, ibm-watson

I have a project where we are required to go through a repository of letters and decide if the letter "passed" or "failed" a certain business rules. We will using Watson Explorer. For me personally, I believe WEX NLP can be used to extract and understand the content, but I am not sure if we need other tools like SPSS Modeller to then score the letters. Or can WEX do that by itself without further tools?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your project use case i.e. "***to go through a repository of letters and decide if the letter "passed" or "failed" a certain business rules***"

Yes, it can be done by making use of Watson Explorer Advanced edition. The Watson Explorer Advanced Edition has 2 major components:

- Watson Explorer Engine (Foundation Component) - It is the component responsible for Big Data Ingestion and it also hosts a UI component called Watson AppBuilder.
- Watson Content Analytics - WCA (Advanced Component) - It is the component responsible for Text annotation, business rule definition and dictionary declaration, bsically text analytics on data.

So, there shouldn't be any need to use SPSS, given that it is an business rule type use case (which can be built in WCA). And can be integrated with the displayed on AppBuilder UI by making use Custom Converter on WEX Engine (where you ingest the data and add converters to make use of the WCA business rules to be applied on the data).

Also, if you are looking at creating your own UI and Backend using some other technology such as Node JS or JAVA (JSP), then you may want to use the WCA or the WEX API's for the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Rakshit, thank you for responding. Since I asked the question, we looked at Watson cloud and used both Watson Knowledge studio to do the annotation and also NLC to classify the content.